# hibernate spring integration with latest release

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

Hi found below forum which describes not to use Spring hibernate template:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?111771-what-is-the-difference-between-hibernate-template-and-hibernate-dao-support.

it says:

> The HibernateTemplate isn't needed anymore since hibernate 3.0.1,
>   since that release it became easier to plugin nicely to hibernate,
>   before that spring needed some trickery, proxing and hackery to manage
>   transactions, thread bound sessions and exception translation. Now
>   with the newer versions of hibernate that isn't needed anymore, you
>   still get all the nice stuff exception translation, session management
>   etc. but without using any spring specific classes. Which imho is
>   really nice it makes the use of spring even less obtrusive.

I used HibernateTemplate and Dao support, is it required to use these API in a new application?

Can I have latest some sample code to integrate Hibernate with Spring framework.

2)

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight

This style is similar to that of the Hibernate reference documentation and examples, except for holding the SessionFactory in an instance variable. We strongly recommend such an instance-based setup over the old-school static HibernateUtil class from Hibernate's CaveatEmptor sample application.

since many place we are using SessionFactory, which is the best way to get session since earlier i used HibernateUtil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Hibernate Session Factory instead of Hibernate Template as:

```
public abstract class HomeSessionFactory {

   @Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

}
```

extend this class in your xxDAOImpl file as.

```
@Repository("LoginDetailsDAO")
@Transactional
public class LoginDetailsDAOImpl extends HomeSessionFactory implements LoginDetailsDAO {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<UserLogin> loginDetails(UserLogin login) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        List<UserLogin> result = session.createQuery("from UserLogin").list();
        transaction.commit();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Spring Context file:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.home.app.model.UserLogin</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>properties/database.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

In previous versions of Spring, the template model was used to provide a common abstraction for many different frameworks (Hibernate, JPA, JMS etc.). While this made developing easy, it also tied your business code to the Spring Framework. One of the goals of Spring 3.x is to decouple your application code from Spring, requiring you to use as little Spring-specific code as possible, thus making your code more reusable.

> The recommended integration style is to code DAOs against plain
>   Hibernate, JPA, and JDO APIs. The older style of using Spring's DAO
>   templates is no longer recommended; however, coverage of this style
>   can be found in the Section A.1, “Classic ORM usage” in the
>   appendices.
>   [[Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html)]

The enhanced functionality provided by Spring (Transaction management, exception translation etc.) now happens through AOP, and you don't have to worry about it in your code. The mechanism is described in:

> [13.3.2. Implementing DAOs based on plain Hibernate 3 API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight)

whereas the legacy approach is covered in

> [Classic ORM Usage: A.1.1.1 The HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-spring.html#orm-hibernate-template)